# Why Scala By-Name parameter syntax fails when removing space between : and =>

Tags: scala, syntax, identifier, lexical-analysis

I am just having a question in my mind regarding the named parameters syntax of Scala. I have created the below running code fragment and it works fine.
However, when I removed the Space between `a: =>Int` to `a:=>Int`, it fails.

This runs without any issues:

```
object Calculator extends App {
  def sum(a: => Int) = (b: Int) => a + b
  println(sum(4)(5))
}
```

The following fails with a syntax error when I remove space at Line 2 in `sum(a:=>Int)`:

```
object Calculator extends App {
  def sum(a:=> Int) = (b: Int) => a + b
  println(sum(4)(5))
}
```

Why doesn't the second code snippet compile?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It fails at the very first stage, during the lexical analysis, because `:=>` is a valid Scala identifier:

```
val :=> = 42
println(:=>)  // prints 42
```

Therefore, your code

```
def sum(a:=> Int) = ??? // wrong: unexpected identifier `:=>`
```

is just as invalid as, say

```
def sum(a+= Int) = ??? // wrong: unexpected identifier `+=`
```

or

```
def sum(a:: Int) = ??? // wrong: unexpected identifier `::`
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, you mean it fails as the ':=>' is a valid identifier and Scala compiler couldn't identify the named parameter due to that. def sum(a: => Int) = ??? // works without error: Not an identifier : => def sum(a:=> Int) = ??? // wrong: unexpected identifier :=>

Comment: @madhawaOnline Again: you code doesn't compile, for exactly the same reason why `def sum(foo bar Int) = ???` wouldn't compile. The compiler simply does not know what to do with two identifiers immediately following each other in the argument list. I don't know how I could possibly express it in any simpler way.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin `:=>` is indeed a valid identifier, but `a:=>` is _not_. So, there is no ambiguity there ...

Comment: @Dima Of course it is not. The string `a:=>` is tokenized as two separate identifiers: `a` followed by `:=>`. It's the same as `a+=b` being tokenized as three separate `identifier` tokens: `a`, `+=`, `b`. So, I can only repeat myself once again: the code in question doesn't compile for exactly the same reason why `def sum(foo bar Int) = ???` wouldn't compile. The code does not have to be ambiguous (have multiple valid parse trees) in order to produce an error. It can also simply have *zero* valid parse trees.

Comment: @Dima Thanks for noting that point , Andrew, yes of course :)